# iPhone program standard for companies?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

I'll publish an application on the store. If I will make a iPhone program standard (99$) account, can I put the name of a society and my name as a developer? (enrollment by a company and not individual ?)

Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one name assigned to the developer account. Apple will require some form of legal documents that proves that the name is valid and that you are allowed to act on behalf of that name.

Your own Apple-ID can be assigned to many developer accounts.

Comment: @ iceydee  So if I want to put the name of the company that develop the application (DEV company) as the developper, and put the name of the company targeted to use the application (SELLER COMPANY), I have to make a iPhone program standart company (for DEV COMPANY) and another standart company (for SELLER COMPANY) ??? so 2*90$ ??? of I can make a free account for the DEV COMPANY ??? thanks to help me ;-)

Comment: @clement If you are going to be releasing applications on behalf of both companies you need two accounts. If DEV COMPANY is not releasing any "own" applications, then SELLER COMPANY will be enough. You will log in with your regular Apple ID (which you use to buy application in app store etc.) - and this is free as always.

Comment: @ iceydee : Thank YOU! SOOO, the best solution could be to publish the app with the SELLER COMPANY accoumpt, and I could put the name of the DEV company as the developer? so only once account for the SELLER company???

Comment: @clement The name assigned to the developer program subscription is what is going to be shown in the app store. You can assign any apple-id to use for uploading the binary and handling the profiles - but only the actual name assigned to the developer program is going to show in the app store.